# Work done by a variable force in two dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, notation

In physics class today, our teacher ended class with an example problem.  It essentially asked (perhaps with different numbers):

> Given a variable force $\vec{F}=3x\hat{\textbf{i}}+4y\hat{\textbf{j}}$ acting on an object moving from $\vec{r}=0$ to $\vec{r}=5\hat{\textbf{i}}$, calculate the work done on the object by $\vec{F}$.

Our teacher wrote  "$\int_{0}^{5}{3x\hat{\textbf{i}}+4y\hat{\textbf{j}} \space dx\hat{\textbf{i}}}$" on the board, which looked wrong.  While the solution to this problem is fairly intuitive, what is the correct notation for the integral and solution in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total work done is

$$W = \int_\gamma \vec F \cdot d \vec r $$

where $d\vec r$ is the infinitesimal, tangential line element along some path $\gamma$.

We need to figure out the path we'd like to take, and the associated parameterization we would like to use.  One possible choice (which mirrors what your instructor used) is the [following](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20(t,0)%20from%20t%3D0%20to%205):

$$\vec r(t) = \langle x(t),y(t) \rangle = \langle t,0\rangle \\ t\in [0,5]$$
[image]
so
$$ \vec F = \langle 3x(t),4y(t)\rangle = \langle 3t,0\rangle$$
$$ d \vec r = \langle 1, 0 \rangle dt$$
and the integral becomes
$$\int_0^5 3t \ dt = \left.\frac{3}{2}t^2\right|^5_0 = \frac{75}{2}$$

Your instructor chose to parameterize the path by one of its coordinates.  That's a perfectly good choice for *that particular path*, but it isn't always possible to do this - in particular, if the path has a squiggle or a loop such that it no longer passes the so-called "vertical line test", you can't use the $x$ coordinate as a valid parameter.  Similarly, if the path doesn't pass the "horizontal line test", then you can't use the $y$ coordinate as a valid parameter.  I like to use a totally separate parameter $t$ which circumvents these issues and makes the parameterization clearer.

---

For a bit of enrichment, notice that we could have chosen a totally different path.  What if we picked a [crazy, loopy path like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20(t%2Bcos(2*pi*t)-1,sin(2*pi*t))%20from%20t%3D0%20to%205)?

$$\vec r(t) = \langle t+\cos(2\pi t)-1,\sin(2\pi t)\rangle \\ t \in [0,5]$$

[image: The path in question]

Notice that this beast does not pass the horizontal or vertical line tests, so I certainly cannot parameterize this path by $x$ or $y$.  However, I can use my parameter $t$ and everything works out just as before.  It's a bit messy, but if you work it out you'll find that you get the same answer as before, and for good reason.

---

**An arbitrary line integral needs to be equipped with a path along which the integration is taking place.**  However, for a special class of integrands, the value of the integral is independent of the path chosen.  This is true whenever $\vec F$ can be written as the gradient of a scalar function,

$$ \vec F = -\nabla U$$

where the minus sign is just a convention commonly used in physics.  In such cases, $\vec F$ is called a conservative vector field, and

$$ \int_A^B \vec F \cdot d \vec r = U(A)-U(B)$$

regardless of the path chosen.  For your $\vec F$, we could pick 
$$U=-\frac{3}{2}x^2 - 2y^2$$
You can check to see that this yields the correct answer.  When $\vec F$ is interpreted as a force, we call an associated function $U$ a potential energy function corresponding to that force.

But once again, **vector fields are not generally conservative**.  When they are not, a line integral is not even defined until you've chosen a path (though you can parameterize that path in essentially whatever way you choose).

Comment: I up voted your answer since I believe it'll be very useful to the OP. The important here are the gradient, the potential and that the integral is independent of the path. But I think that you might omit the full solutions because this is a homework like question, for example: the value of the integral and the potential $\:U\:$ leaving the OP to find out them by him(/her)self.